# issue with IKM for incremental update when using a sequence in target table

Tags: oracle, oracle12c, oracle-data-integrator

ENG_ENG_OPE is my target take a look at what I set for it:

logical :
[image]

physical :

[image]

when I run this Mapping I get this error :

[image]

Comment: If you click on the "code" tab of the failed task, what SQL command is generated?

Comment: @MarcoBaldelli thanks for your comment, I will publish a solution please take a look at it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In the properties of the column with the sequence set the property Execute on Hint to Target
this solved the problem

[image]

Comment: In ODI, Sequence should be executed on Target and not source.

Comment: Nice to see you here in this community as a developer ODI